# Centos 7 Teamviewer square brackets

Tags: linux, centos, teamviewer

I have installed Centos 7 minimal core on a machine and remoting to it with TeamViewer. 
Can anyone tell me why I can't type square bracket, pipeline and so on.
I can only do it on the physical keyboard/computer

I can do it on windows OS.

I have a danish keyboard, I normally use alt + 8 to make brackets

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable key combinations:

```
Action -> Send key combination
```